# python unsupervised learning dbscan scikit application example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dbscan, unsupervised-learning

I have following list that I would like to perform unsupervised learning on and use the knowledge to predict a value for each item in the test list

```
#Format [real_runtime, processors, requested_time, score, more_to_be_added]
#some entries from the list
```

### Training dataset

```
Xsrc = [['354', '2048', '3600', '53.0521472395'], 
      ['605', '2048', '600', '54.8768871369'], 
      ['128', '2048', '600', '51.0'], 
      ['136', '2048', '900', '51.0000000563'], 
      ['19218', '480', '21600', '51.0'], 
      ['15884', '2048', '18000', '51.0'], 
      ['118', '2048', '1500', '51.0'], 
      ['103', '2048', '2100', '51.0000002839'], 
      ['18542', '480', '21600', '51.0000000001'], 
      ['13272', '2048', '18000', '51.0000000001']]
```

### Test data set

Using the clusters I would like to predict the *real_runtime* of a new list:
    Xtest= [['-1', '2048', '1500', '51.0000000161'],
           ['-1', '2048', '10800', '51.0000000002'],
           ['-1', '512', '21600', '-1'], 
           ['-1', '512', '2700', '51.0000000004'],
           ['-1, '1024', '21600', '51.1042617556']]

## Code: Formatting the list and Making clusters using scikit in python and plotting the clusters

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##Training dataset
Xsrc = [['354', '2048', '3600', '53.0521472395'], 
      ['605', '2048', '600', '54.8768871369'], 
      ['128', '2048', '600', '51.0'], 
      ['136', '2048', '900', '51.0000000563'], 
      ['19218', '480', '21600', '51.0'], 
      ['15884', '2048', '18000', '51.0'], 
      ['118', '2048', '1500', '51.0'], 
      ['103', '2048', '2100', '51.0000002839'], 
      ['18542', '480', '21600', '51.0000000001'], 
      ['13272', '2048', '18000', '51.0000000001']]

print "Xsrc:", Xsrc

##Test data set
Xtest= [['1224', '2048', '1500', '51.0000000161'],
       ['7867', '2048', '10800', '51.0000000002'],
       ['21594', '512', '21600', '-1'], 
       ['1760', '512', '2700', '51.0000000004'],
       ['115', '1024', '21600', '51.1042617556']]


##Clustering 
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(Xsrc)
db = DBSCAN(min_samples=2).fit(X) #no clustering parameter, such as default eps
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
clusters = [X[labels == i] for i in xrange(n_clusters_)]

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f" % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))


##Plotting the dataset
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = 'k'

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=20)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=10)


plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Any ideas how I can use the clusters to predict the value?

Comment: Why are you clustering, rather than doing a simple multivariate regression?

Comment: As Prune already suggested - there is no point in doing clustering in the first place. The only reason to do so would be because you have some idea how to use it later, and **not doing** that **did not work**. In general - this is not how you should approach the problem, start with simplest solutions and if they fail - look for some more complex ones.

Comment: The initial idea was to learn from hundreds of records and use that knowledge to predict one attribute of the next one. They reason I considered clustering is because the new record(predict) will have similarities to some of the records learned(processed) so far not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clustering is not prediction

There is little use in "predicting" a cluster label, because it was just assigned "randomly" by the clustering algorithm.

Even worse: most algorithms cannot incorporate new data.

You really should use clustering to explore your data, and learn what is there and what not. **Do not rely on the clustering being 'good'.**

Sometimes, people have success with *quantizing* the data set into k centers, and then using only this "compressed" data set for classification/prediction (usually based on the nearest neighbor only). I have also seen the idea around of training onemregression per cluster for prediction, and choosing the regressor to apply using nearest neighbors (i.e. if the data fits a cluster well, use the clusters regression model). But I don't remember any major success stories...